# How do I link to an external <div> with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, external

I have an external script which I'm linking to, and it calculates a `<div>` element in my `HTML` page.  The div name is `totalDiv`, and I have it display a calculated amount in the page.  It won't let me specify which `div` I'm wanting, so I was wondering if I should do something like `formId.totalDiv.value`.  Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you describe better your problem... Post (the relevant slice of) your markup/script would help too...

Comment: I assume that when you say "external" you mean a JavaScript file you can't edit directly?

Comment: You say that the name of the div is "totalDiv". FYI, the name attribute is used primarily for form fields (<input>, <select>, etc). For all other elements, you should give them unique identifiers using an id tag instead: <div id="totalDiv"></div>

Comment: @NemoStein: I have linked to an external script of mine (@Levi Hackwith: I can edit it, but it's not in the HTML page.) using a `<script type="text/javascript" src="Script src goes here">` format.  The script allows you to automatically calculate values, and shows the total in a `div`.  The line of script is: `    document.getElementById('totalDiv').innerHTML = round_decimals(order_total, 2);`.

Comment: @Luke Dennis:  I am giving it a unique identifier.  The script can be found [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/NwkQW/8/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use jQuery. To set a value use `$("#totalDiv").html("your text here");`

Or

Without jQuery use `document.getElementById("totalDiv").innerHTML = "your text here";`